# Problem installing docker on kali linux?

Tags: package-management, kali-linux, docker

I want to install MongoDB on Kali linux but it didn't get install.
The problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251273/problem-installing-mongodb-using-apt-get/251282#251282) is explained.
Now is a try to install MongoDB using Docker for which I am following [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/debian/#debian-wheezy-stable-7-x-64-bit) tutorial.
Now when I run this:

```
apt-get purge lxc-docker*
```

It says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lxc-docker*
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lxc-docker*'
```

What is the problem.

Comment: You're getting that error because it's not installed and you're trying to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

**apt-get remove** - Packages installed are removed (Does NOT include configuration files)

**apt-get purge**:  Purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged. Purge meaning that any configuration files are deleted too.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove

If Kali cannot find the package then it simple never got installed properly. Maybe you got a error during installation. Kali is simply saying: "yo bro, that package does not exists on your entire disk. Then how should I delete it." (In my head, Linux is speaking with a new jersey accent :) )